# Writing HTML to a user control

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, user-controls

I'm creating a web user control and want to get some html from a datasource and write it to the page. I initially though I should just use response.write, but the problem with that is it writes the message above everything in the page the user control lives in - I guess because the uc is built before the page.

Does any one know of a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Literal control to write HTML code